# Prompt ABPersonViewController with uniqueID

Tags: objective-c, abpersonviewcontroller

I want to load a existing contact using the address book view controller using only the uniqueID of the contact. How can a "person" record be defined using only the uniqueID?

```
ABPersonViewController *view = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

view.personViewDelegate = self;
view.displayedPerson = person; 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this it what you are asking, but you create a *person* for ABPersonViewController like this.

```
CFErrorRef err;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &err);
ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, [contact.recordId intValue]);

personVC.displayedPerson = person;
```

Comment: Thats what I wanted. Thank you.